# Jenkins is reserved for jobs with matching label expression

Tags: jenkins

I have installed blue-ocean plugin and create a simple pipeline with print message. When I run the pipeline, build job hang with below message

```
Queued Jenkins is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
```

How to get rid of this message and build the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could prevent this error and continue the build by assigning a slave node with a label. I have done this by editing the pipeline and assigning label for agent option.

**EDIT**

When I further checked settings section, I could notice that, Amazon EC2 Plugin is installed in this Jenkins instance and all the `clouds` available are using this configuration.

```
Usage : Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node
```

Comment: Can someone further explain the solution? How do I *"assign a slave node with a label"* ?

Comment: @shellwhale from the [official docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent): `agent { label 'my-defined-label' }`