# reserved for jobs with matching label expression when using declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I'm tasked to write Jenkinsfiles for a Jenkins cluster that I do not manage.
I'm facing an issue where some of my jobs are hanging with the message `"xxxx is reserved for jobs with matching label expression"` **only when using declarative pipeline**.

However that does not occurs with scripted pipelines.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30', artifactNumToKeepStr: '30'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("Hello") {

            steps {
                sh 'echo hello'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I saw this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/876621/jenkins-is-reserved-for-jobs-with-matching-label-expression) but the vague solution (lack of example) didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins is reserved for jobs with matching label expression](https://serverfault.com/questions/876621/jenkins-is-reserved-for-jobs-with-matching-label-expression)